Why my expo app size increased when I added application icon
I have an expo app built with EAS . The application size was 18MB but when I added the application icon in png format into the assets/images  directory with specifying path in app.json file the application size increased from 18MB to 75MB but the image size was 4KB.
When I try to built app I have used these commands in order:
for publishing on google play console:
eas build --p android

for apk:
eas build -p android --profile preview

This is my application.json file:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My App",
    "slug": "my-app",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "android": {
      "package": "com.my.app",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "***********"
        }
      }
    },
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.my.app", 
      "buildNumber": "1.0.1",
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "*********"
      } 
    },
    "splash": {
      "image": "./app/assetsApp/logobig.png",  
      "resizeMode": "contain",         
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"     
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "***********"
      }
    },
    "owner": "my-app"
  }
}

eas.json:
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 12.5.1",
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "autoIncrement": true,
      "developmentClient": false, 
      "distribution": "store"     
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

babel.config.js:
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ["nativewind/babel", "react-native-reanimated/plugin"]
  };
};

Anyone has idea about this issue ?  I couldn't figure out  why application size increased over than image size.
